# what's the windows equivalent of Unix `**`

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

Is there a simple way to have windows `cmd` window match *all files matching a pattern, recursively*, as in

```
rm **/*.tmp
```

See [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47858/how-can-i-search-a-wild-card-name-in-all-subfolders) for how it works on Unix

(I'm not sure all Unix shells react well to this, but at least bash and zsh do)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the nearest equivalent is `del /S {pattern}`

```
C:\Users\RGB> dir /S/B t
C:\Users\RGB\t\f1.foo
C:\Users\RGB\t\f1.txt
C:\Users\RGB\t\f2.txt
C:\Users\RGB\t\t2
C:\Users\RGB\t\t2\f3.txt
C:\Users\RGB\t\t2\f4.foo

C:\Users\RGB> del /S t\*.foo
Deleted file - C:\Users\RGB\t\f1.foo
Deleted file - C:\Users\RGB\t\t2\f4.foo

C:\Users\RGB> dir /S/B t
C:\Users\RGB\t\f1.txt
C:\Users\RGB\t\f2.txt
C:\Users\RGB\t\t2
C:\Users\RGB\t\t2\f3.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `FOR /R` to loop through files/folders. Read more about what you can do with the command [here](http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html)

For example for your example it would be something like:

```
For /R C:\ %G IN (*.tmp) do del "%G"
```

If you want to use this in a batch file us `%%G` instead of `%G`

Answer (score 2):

The answer is: no, there is not a way to do that.

Your question seems to be about how to simply use **, which may be useful in a variety of circumstances.

This is simply not supported in the DOS-like command prompt (CMD.EXE).

A key thing to understand is that the command line interpretor (COMMAND.COM in traditional DOS) doesn't actually support wildcards, and neither does the CMD program built in Windows NT, 2K, XP, and subsequent versions of Microsoft Windows.

DOS did support wildcards with many of its commands, like XCOPY, and even including some commands like DIR which were built into the DOS command line shell.  (Depending on the version, deleting recursively might be available with an external DELTREE command, or an internal command like DEL or RMDIR.)  However, every individual command provided its own support for understanding the wildcards.  The actual command line interpreter simply passed the wildcards to the commands.  So, if you had some command that didn't support wildcards (e.g., EDIT in DOS, or NOTEPAD in Microsoft Windows), then the command shell wouldn't take care of that for you.

In contrast, in Unix, the shell program interprets the wildcards.  Individual programs usually don't have any support for wildcards.  One exception I can readily think of is the "find" command.  In order to allow the "find" command to receive a wildcard, you may need to escape it.  Escaping characters can also be useful whenever wishing to pass certain symbols to a program that supports "regular expressions".  Such escaping isn't typically necessary in DOS, because in DOS, the command line parameter doesn't tend to muck with the symbols you give it.  (Again, Windows inherits DOS's behavior, which is a result of earlier Windows versions striving rather hard to be mostly compatible with DOS.)

Note: I'm not disagreeing with [pungk's excellent answer](http://superuser.com/a/1141144/401839), which gives a practical workaround for many circumstances.  If you want to do something recursively, that may be an option.  I'm simply saying that you may need to do something like that, instead of just using wildcards, because wildcards aren't something interpreted by the command line parser.

Other option may be to use options in a program, like [RedGrittyBrick's answer](http://superuser.com/a/1141132/401839), which specifies how to delete files recursively in modern Windows versions (which seems appropriate for your example of deleting files recursively in Unix).  This is often the easiest way to do things.  However, your ability to do this will vary based on which program you are using.  In Unix, -R may be the most common for recursion, with -r being the second-most-common.  In DOS/Windows, /s is most common.  However, there are exceptions.

Another option, of course, may be to use a Unix shell in Windows.  (This is especially true with a release of Windows 10 which has a built-in option to install a Linux Subsystem feature, providing a version of bash.)

Comment: Great explanation. It makes big sense